# Extending AbstractCassandraConfiguration is ignoring application.yml auto configuration

Tags: spring-data-cassandra, spring-boot-starter

I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive(version 3.2.4) and have provided all the spring.data.cassaandra properties is application.yml. It works fine. But I need to add some customCassandraConversion so I extended AbstractCassandraConfiguration. The moment I extend AbstractCassandraConfiguration the application.yml aka the CassandraAutoConfiguration stops working. Is there another way to to configure customConversions without overriding AbstractCassandraConfiguration. Or how can I get both working? I'm using spring-boot 2.5.4

Answer (score 0):

You can register your custom conversions as a Bean in config and they'll be picked up by AbstractCassandraConfiguration.

```
@Bean
public CassandraCustomConversions customConversions() {
   // Add your converters here
   List<?> converters = Arrays.asList(...)
   return new CassandraCustomConversions(convert));
}
```